AGPL 3.0 library used as a back-end service
I have read that an AGPL database is safe to use without sharing the code because it is running as some kind of support for the application that you are serving to the customer. But what if it is not your direct product/service but used in generating something for the customers?
We have a SaaS application(rebranded by clients) composed of multiple microservices, and one of the microservices was used for generating receipts, quotations, and legal documents that will be sent to the customers later. These generated files are not our main product/service, but something like auxiliary or something? I'm not really sure about these technicalities.
Are we obliged to at least open source the microservice that uses the AGPL 3.0 library? I'm thinking about using iText for conversion of HTML to PDF, where HTML will be used for easier templating.
In case of extending this feature and make a UI for making and managing templates of forms and use the library's feature of converting PDF to HTML, that can be accessed by the client(not the customer).


These generated files are not our main product/service, but something like auxiliary or something? I'm not really sure about these technicalities.

For copyright license obligations, it does not matter if something is part of your core business or ancillary. The only relevant consideration is who you make the software available to and in what way/form.
The requirements of the AGPL are:

If part of an application (microservice?) is under the AGPL license, then the entire application needs to be distributed under the AGPL license, when it gets distributed.
You must give (a link to) the source code to whoever receives a copy of the binary
You must give (a link to) the source code to whoever interacts remotely with the AGPL code. If the interaction happens by an employee as part of their official duties, I would argue that it is the employer who gets the right to receive the source code.


Are we obliged to at least open source the microservice that uses the AGPL 3.0 library?

Yes, I would say so. That does not mean the general public must be offered the code to that microservice. Only your clients receive the binary or interact with it, so they are the only ones who get a right to receive the source code and make modifications to it.
